# Why Jupyter runs on local host if Anaconda is installed

Tags: localhost, anaconda, jupyter

Why Jupyter runs on local host if Anaconda is installed in the system? Also, is there any command to check which version of Pyhon it is running on?

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed anaconda in your local machine, jupyter notebook will be installed by default and hence it is showing as localhost.In command prompt if you type python,it will show the python version you are running on.

You can create new conda environment and take jupyter for that environment using the below commands

conda create -n env_name -c intel python=3.6

source activate env_name

conda install ipykernel

ipython kernel install --name  env_name --user

where env_name is the environment name that you want to create

Comment: Thanks, Lakshmi for your answer! I think you meant, installed 'Anaconda' instead of Python in the first line of your reply. I have 4 different versions of Python installed on my machine. I installed them through python.org and one got installed by default with Anaconda. So, the commands that you have mentioned can be run in Conda navigator, right?. What will happen if I install ipykernel, as mentioned in the third line of the command?

Comment: You can open either anaconda prompt or command prompt  and create a new conda environment using the first step I mentioned. You can activate that environment using the 2nd step. After executing step 3 and 4,you can see the environment you created now  in your jupyter notebook kernel->change kernel tab.You can select that environment and  start working in that environment.